# How to instantiate the JQuery widget - what text to use

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, instantiation

I have created a working widget, but I do not know how to instantiate the code to run on the page (it looks great in view source when I save the page).  I have tried

```
      // ===== Instantiate Carousel ===== //
      jQuery("#carousel").carousel();

      // ===== Instantiate Carousel ===== //
      jQuery("#carousel");
```

Please see demo here: [Demo Link](http://www.powerflexweb.com/widget_sites/active/full.php?format=carousel&color=light_blue_green&id_language=003001)

Neither work.  This carousel is W3C Bootstrap Carousel. I have read about getting the widget to instantiate, and I have a working tabs widget that uses the first method above (with the words tabs instead of carousel) - but that widget uses JQueryUI and the carousel one does not...

```
 function searchCallback(data) {
      if(debug_messages){console.log("json data loaded.");}
      // ===== Inject UL tag ===== //
      jQuery("#carousel").addClass( "carousel slide" ).attr('data-ride', 'carousel').append('<ul class="carousel-indicator">');
      var ws_ftr = data.ws_ftr.records;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(ws_ftr));
      jQuery.each(ws_ftr, function(index, ftr) {
           jQuery("#carousel>ul").append('<li data-target="carousel" data-slide-to="'+ftr[0]+'"></li>');
           jQuery(".carousel li:first").addClass("active");
      });
      jQuery("#carousel>ul").after('<div class="carousel-inner">');
      jQuery.each(ws_ftr, function(index, ftr) {
           jQuery(".carousel-inner").append('<div class="carousel-item"><img src="img/features_sliding/' + ftr[3] + '" alt="feature - ' + ftr[2] + '"/>');
           jQuery(".carousel-inner");
           jQuery(".carousel-item li:first").addClass("active");
      });
      jQuery(".carousel-inner").after('<!-- Left and right controls --><a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev"><span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span></a><a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next"><span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span></a>');  
      // ===== Instantiate Carousel ===== //
      jQuery("#carousel").carousel();
 };
```

Comment: do you mean nothing happens when you do this `jQuery("#carousel").carousel()`? maybe that is not the way the carousel plugin is set up, check the docs and examples on how to initialize it

Comment: What errors do you get? Post a [mcve] please

Comment: You can see the demo here: 
http://www.powerflexweb.com/widget_sites/active/full.php?format=carousel&color=light_blue_green&id_language=003001

You can see in the console.log that all is fine - just not showing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply do not add the `active` class correctly.

In this part:

```
jQuery.each(ws_ftr, function(index, ftr) {
  jQuery(".carousel-inner").append('<div class="carousel-item"><img src="img/features_sliding/' + ftr[3] + '" alt="feature - ' + ftr[2] + '"/>');
  jQuery(".carousel-inner"); // <-- No use for that line, remove it...
  jQuery(".carousel-item li:first").addClass("active");  // Problem is here!
});
```

Replace:

```
jQuery(".carousel-item li:first").addClass("active");
```

With:

```
$(".carousel-item").first().addClass("active");
```

The`.carousel-item` are `div`s... Not `li`. And add the class after the `.each()` loop has completed.

Result:

```
jQuery.each(ws_ftr, function(index, ftr) {
  jQuery(".carousel-inner").append('<div class="carousel-item"><img src="img/features_sliding/' + ftr[3] + '" alt="feature - ' + ftr[2] + '"/>');
});
$(".carousel-item").first().addClass("active");  // Place it here, after the each loop.
```

;)

Comment: That was it!! I guess I just didn't know what I didn't know! Thanks for educating me, every little bit helps and eventually I will be able to write the code much faster haha - thanks again! :)